# Is np.argsort returning the correct answer?

Tags: python, numpy

I expected the answer to be completely and else and I don't know on what basis it is sorting the indices. It should have sorted the array in increasing order, but I am not able to figure out what it did.

```
>>> random_array
array([[63, 28, 16,  5, 35],
       [77, 32, 87, 95, 33],
       [45, 40, 91, 14, 45]])

>>> np.argsort(random_array)
array([[3, 2, 1, 4, 0],
       [1, 4, 0, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 0, 4, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Expected answer:

```
[[4,2,1,0,3] 
 [2,0,3,4,1]
 [3,1,4,0,2]]
```

Comment: Looking at the first row of data, it should be sorted 5, 16, 28, 35, 63. These correspond do indices 3, 2, 1, 4, 0 as `np.argsort` says... Why did you expect 4, 2, 1, 0, 3? That would mean they're sorted as 35, 16, 28, 63, 5.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) It is almost always better to include it as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: @Kiran, please don't inline screenshots of code. New users are prevented from including inline images because a lot of them post screenshots of code. Inlining these images defeats the purpose of that restriction. Instead, ask them to post the code as text, and why we don't like images of code. See my comment above

Answer (score 3):

[`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is giving you the indices of the sorted order. It looks like you're looking for the rank:

```
np.argsort(np.argsort(a))
```

Or use alternatives [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html):

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

rankdata(a, axis=-1, method='ordinal')-1
```

Or [`pandas.DataFrame.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(a).rank(axis=1, method='first').sub(1).to_numpy(dtype=a.dtype)
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 2, 1, 0, 3],
       [2, 0, 3, 4, 1],
       [2, 1, 4, 0, 3]])
```

##### note

In the third row of the provided output, you ranked the first 45 after the second 45. To achieve this you would need to rank the left-right  flipped array:

```
np.argsort(np.argsort(a[:, ::-1]))[:, ::-1]

np.fliplr(np.argsort(np.argsort(np.fliplr(a))))

rankdata(a[: , ::-1], axis=-1, method='ordinal')[: , ::-1]-1

(pd.DataFrame(a[:, ::-1]).rank(axis=1, method='first')
   .sub(1).to_numpy(dtype=a.dtype)[:, ::-1]
)
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 2, 1, 0, 3],
       [2, 0, 3, 4, 1],
       [3, 1, 4, 0, 2]])
```

Reproducible input:

```
a = np.array([[63, 28, 16,  5, 35],
              [77, 32, 87, 95, 33],
              [45, 40, 91, 14, 45]])
```